# Probability with ten-sided dice and rerolls

Tags: probability, dice

I was trying to find what is the probability of rolling 3 successes when rolling four d10 (ten-sided dice), with a success being any result of 7+, and I decided to use the AnyDice web app.

The result the app gave me was 17.92% for 3 successes and 52.48% for 2 successes. I then wanted to see how re-rolling 1 failure affected my chances of rolling 3 successes, and I tried using 2 different ways.

A) Since rolling again a die that showed a failure in the first roll gives a 40% for a success, I multiplied 52,48% * 0.4 to find the probability of rolling 3 successes with that second roll. This gives a ~21%.

B) For the second method, I decided to use AnyDice again, but this time calculate the probability of rolling 3 successes when rolling five d10. In my mind rolling 4 dice and re-rolling 1 failure was the same as rolling 5 dice and finding the 3 success % directly. This gave 31.74%, quite higher than the result of the first method.

So my questions are
1) Which result is the correct one?
2) If in the first method the re-rolled die is again a failure and I decide to roll it a third time, the probability of rolling 3 successes (accounting for action economy) is: 52.48% * 0.6 (for failing the 2nd roll) * 0.4 (for the 3rd roll) ~ 12.6%, right?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, the first result (17,92%) seems to be the answer for "... **at least 3** successes out of 4". This is because this probability can be calculated like so:
$$
{4\choose{3}} \left( \frac{4}{10} \right)^3 \left( \frac{6}{10} \right)^1 + 
{4\choose{4}} \left( \frac{4}{10} \right)^4 \left( \frac{6}{10} \right)^0
= \frac{112}{625} = 0.1792
$$
(this is, of course, not the answer to the question, but it can help you get started with any theoretical calculations)

Comment: “If ... the rerolled die is again a failure and I decide to roll it a third time...” How many times are you allowed to reroll a failure?

Comment: The probabilities that you say you got from AnyDice are incorrect, most likely because of the way you computed them. `output [count {7,8,9,10} in 4d10]` gives me `34.56%` and `15.36%`, respectively for exactly 2 or 3 hits. This agrees with what I computed myself using the [binomial distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: @ amd 
I used the following code in AnyDice:

loop N over {4}{
 output Nd{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1} named "[N]d10.7+"
}
which I think is correct. If you notice any mistake, please let me know.

Comment: I checked again and you are correct. I chosen the "At least" option, instead of "Normal"

Comment: It’s not entirely clear to me what the process you’re trying to model here is. The sample space for trying to get _exactly_ 3 hits is different from that when you’re trying for the maximum number of hits: in the former situation, you’d stop rolling once you got to 3; in the latter, you’d reasonably use all available rerolls.